# what's the .Rtr file for R session log?

Tags: eclipse, r

I use Eclipse/statet R plug in on Windows. In my home directory, there are .Rtr extension files that automatically generated for every R session. file names like yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss.Rtr.
Can someone give me any hint where there files come from? How did I enable it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any documentation on it, so my best guess is that it's related to the RMI Registry.  You can change the settings on that by going `Preferences > StatET > R Interaction > Advanced Options`.

That said, you are unlikely to get an answer here.  You should consider reaching out to Stephan Wahlbrink directly if this is important.